# Getting : ValueError: Expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [100, 1000] on running model.fit() in tensorflow's keras module

Tags: python, deep-learning, tf.keras

So I am trying to make a CNN for doing sentiment analysis on COVID19 tweets. I have made a basic CNN which is supposed to be trained from the top 1000 word count vector of each tweet which are labelled as positive or negative.

#### Shapes of variables

```
features.shape : (100000, 1000)
labels.shape : (100000,)
```

### Model

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(input_shape=(100000,1000),filters=64,kernel_size=(3),padding="same", activation="relu",))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(2),strides=(2)))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(2),strides=(2)))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=(2),strides=(2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=512,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=512,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', monitor='loss', verbose=0,
    save_best_only=True, mode='auto', save_freq=1)
```

Now, the model compiles just fine and I think that the input shape is as per the documentation too i.e (Number of elements, Length of each element).

The problem arises when I try to run the .fit() function.

```py
hist=model.fit(features, labels, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Here I get...

#### ValueError

```
Epoch 1/1000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-be37a193e07d> in <module>()
----> 1 hist=model.fit(features, labels, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, callbacks=[checkpoint])

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:531 train_step  **
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:886 __call__
        self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:180 assert_input_compatibility
        str(x.shape.as_list()))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [100, 1000]
```

I have tried to make different variations which I thought could potentially be the issue but no luck. I don't face any issue in Conv2D which simply takes the shape of a single element as the input_size and the whole features and labels array in the .fit() method. So, what more needs to be done here with Conv1D other than the different input_size format which I have already given.

Answer (score 1):

```
features.shape : (100000, 1000)
labels.shape : (100000,)
```

You input shape should not be `(100000, 1000)`, Instead it should be `(1000, )`
And you need to reshape your label to `(1000000, 1)`.
The first dimension in your `feature.shape` represent the count of training examples. Its not included in dimension of input.

The input shape you provide is shape of individual training example and not of your complete dataset.

Comment: No, setting the input size to (1000, ) didn't work. Anyway, I was able to find my mistake and have posted an answer.

Comment: It depends how u reshaped your dataset.  for `(100000, 1000, )`  input shape is `(1000, )` and for `(100000, 1000, 1)` its `(1000, 1)`. It didnt work cause u reshaped your data. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, now I get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so taking references from the Conv2D's input_size format, I `reshaped` the whole features array to `(100000,1000,1)` and set the `input_size` to `(1000,1)` and it worked.